# Extract Latitude and Longitude of a marker placed on the map using click_for_marker from the folium package

Tags: leaflet, folium

I am using Folium package in Python with click_for_marker.

[image: Click_for_marker]

Once I click on the map, it displays the latitude and longitude in the popup. I want to extract that latitude and longitude and use it to draw a circle of certain radius using the circle_marker function in python.

How exactly can I extract this latitude and longitude information obtained from click_for_marker and making the whole experience dynamic where when ever I click on the map, it needs to display a circle of certain radius?

kindly help.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Folium, but it doesn't look possible to do what you're asking, since the `click_for_marker` function generates code that doesn't return a handle to the generated marker. If you want to write highly interactive Leaflet, you're much better off just...writing Leaflet.

Comment: Is this in an IPython notebook? Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Any progress on this?